# Element-wise multidimensional array iteration regardless of storage order

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have a n-dimensional array class and I would like to be able to iterate though the elements in a specific order, let's say rows first, and thus regardless of the storage order (row or column major).

The signature of the array class is `template<typename T, StorageOrder T_storageOrder, std::size_t ... T_dimensions> class Array`, I have a `storageIndex()` function that converts a list of indices into a 1-D index to retrieve the internal data, and there is an `ElementWiseIterator` class for the iteration logic.

Everything works well but for the end iterator in the column-major case. The idea behind the end iterator is to use the `storageIndex()` function to retrieve a 1-D index from a list of indices that is out of range of the array shape defined by the `T_dimensions` template parameter. In other words, if I have a `2 × 3` array, then I'm trying to retrieve an index that is located at `{2, 0}`, but this (rightfully) returns me the 3rd element when using a column-major order array, instead of returning the 7th (non existing) element as I'd need to represent the end iterator.

This leads me to believe that my approach is flawed but I have no other idea at the moment and am looking for a bit of inspiration to come up with a clean and generic approach. I had a look at `numpy.nditer` but couldn't understand anything of the implementation.

I was also wondering if the `ElementWiseIterator` couldn't be simplified a bit because it currently requires to hold quite some data.

Please find below a reduction of the code.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
constexpr T product(T unique)
{ return unique; }

template<typename T, typename ... T_Others>
constexpr T product(T first, T second, T_Others ... others)
{ return product(first * second, others ...); }

enum class StorageOrder {
    rowMajor,
    columnMajor
};

template<StorageOrder> struct StorageOrderTag {};
using RowMajorStorageOrderTag = StorageOrderTag<StorageOrder::rowMajor>;
using ColumnMajorStorageOrderTag = StorageOrderTag<StorageOrder::columnMajor>;


// - Converts a list of indices for a specific shape array into a 1-D index.

template<typename T_Shape>
std::size_t storageIndex(const T_Shape &indices, const T_Shape &shape, RowMajorStorageOrderTag)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    std::size_t out = indices[i];
    while (i++ < indices.size() - 1) {
        out = indices[i] + shape[i] * out;
    }

    return out;
}

template<typename T_Shape>
std::size_t storageIndex(const T_Shape &indices, const T_Shape &shape, ColumnMajorStorageOrderTag)
{
    std::size_t i = indices.size() - 1;
    std::size_t out = indices[i];
    while (i-- > 0) {
        out = indices[i] + shape[i] * out;
    }

    return out;
}


//- Element-wise iterator.

template<
    typename T,
    typename T_Data,
    StorageOrder T_storageOrder,
    std::size_t T_dimensionality
>
class ElementWiseIterator
    : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>
{
private:
    using Shape = std::array<std::size_t, T_dimensionality>;

public:
    T & operator*() const
    { return *_currentElement; }

    ElementWiseIterator & operator++()
    {
        std::size_t i = _shape.size();
        while (i-- > 0) {
            if (_currentIndices[i] < _shape[i] - 1 || i == 0) {
                ++_currentIndices[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        for (++i; i < _currentIndices.size(); ++i) {
            _currentIndices[i] = 0;
        }

        setCurrentElement();
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const ElementWiseIterator &iterator1, const ElementWiseIterator &iterator2)
    { return iterator1._currentElement == iterator2._currentElement; }

    friend bool operator!=(const ElementWiseIterator &iterator1, const ElementWiseIterator &iterator2)
    { return !(iterator1 == iterator2); }

private:
    ElementWiseIterator(T_Data *data, const Shape &indices, const Shape &shape)
        : _currentElement(nullptr),
          _data(data),
          _currentIndices(indices),
          _shape(shape)
    {
        setCurrentElement();
    }

    void setCurrentElement()
    {
        std::size_t index = storageIndex(
            _currentIndices,
            _shape,
            StorageOrderTag<T_storageOrder>()
        );

        _currentElement = &(*_data)[index];
    }

    T *_currentElement;
    T_Data *_data;
    Shape _currentIndices;
    Shape _shape;

    template<typename, StorageOrder, std::size_t ...> friend class Array;
};


//- Array class.

template<typename T, StorageOrder T_storageOrder, std::size_t ... T_dimensions>
class Array
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t size()
    { return product(T_dimensions ...); }

    using Shape = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof ... (T_dimensions)>;

    static constexpr Shape shape()
    { return {T_dimensions ...}; }

protected:
    using Storage = std::array<T, size()>;

public:
    using Iterator = typename Storage::iterator;
    using ElementWiseIterator = ElementWiseIterator<
        T,
        Storage,
        T_storageOrder,
        sizeof ... (T_dimensions)
    >;

    Iterator begin()
    { return _data.begin(); }

    Iterator end()
    { return _data.end(); }

    ElementWiseIterator elementWiseBegin()
    { return ElementWiseIterator(&_data, {0}, shape()); }

    ElementWiseIterator elementWiseEnd()
    {
        // Set the current iterator indices to the first out of range element.
        // Ie: for an a 2x3 array, that would be {2, 0}.
        Shape shape = this->shape();
        return ElementWiseIterator(&_data, {shape[0]}, shape);
    }

    T & operator[](std::size_t index)
    { return _data[index]; }

    const T & operator[](std::size_t index) const
    { return _data[index]; }

private:
    Storage _data;
};


template<typename T, StorageOrder T_storageOrder, std::size_t ... T_dimensions>
void printDebug(Array<T, T_storageOrder, T_dimensions ...> &array)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    auto it = array.elementWiseBegin();
    for (; i < array.size(); ++i, ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 2, 3> rowArray2d;
    Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 2, 3> colArray2d;

    Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 4, 2, 3> rowArray3d;
    Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 4, 2, 3> colArray3d;

    {
        std::cout << "\nTest case 1\n"
                  << "-----------\n"
                  << "Both arrays represent the same 2x3 matrix:\n"
                  << "  0 1 2\n"
                  << "  3 4 5"
                  << std::endl;

        rowArray2d[0] = 0; rowArray2d[1] = 1; rowArray2d[2] = 2;
        rowArray2d[3] = 3; rowArray2d[4] = 4; rowArray2d[5] = 5;

        colArray2d[0] = 0; colArray2d[2] = 1; colArray2d[4] = 2;
        colArray2d[1] = 3; colArray2d[3] = 4; colArray2d[5] = 5;

        // Below returns 0 1 2 3 4 5 as expected.
        std::cout << "element-wise iteration over rowArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = rowArray2d.elementWiseBegin(); it != rowArray2d.elementWiseEnd(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        // Below returns only 0 instead of 0 1 2 3 4 5.
        std::cout << "element-wise iteration over colArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = colArray2d.elementWiseBegin(); it != colArray2d.elementWiseEnd(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        // But if we increment using the `elementWiseBegin` iterator and use the
        // index number as a stop condition, then it works well.
        std::cout << "debug element-wise iteration over colArray2d:\n  ";
        printDebug(colArray2d);


        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = rowArray2d.begin(); it != rowArray2d.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over colArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = colArray2d.begin(); it != colArray2d.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\nTest case 2\n"
                  << "-----------\n"
                  << "Both arrays share the same internal 1-D representation:\n"
                  << "  0 1 2 3 4 5"
                  << std::endl;

        rowArray2d[0] = 0; rowArray2d[1] = 1; rowArray2d[2] = 2;
        rowArray2d[3] = 3; rowArray2d[4] = 4; rowArray2d[5] = 5;

        colArray2d[0] = 0; colArray2d[2] = 2; colArray2d[4] = 4;
        colArray2d[1] = 1; colArray2d[3] = 3; colArray2d[5] = 5;

        // Below returns 0 1 2 3 4 5 as expected.
        std::cout << "element-wise iteration over rowArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = rowArray2d.elementWiseBegin(); it != rowArray2d.elementWiseEnd(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        // Below returns only 0 instead of 0 2 4 1 3 5.
        std::cout << "element-wise iteration over colArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = colArray2d.elementWiseBegin(); it != colArray2d.elementWiseEnd(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 2 4 1 3 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        // But if we increment using the `elementWiseBegin` iterator and use the
        // index number as a stop condition, then it works well.
        std::cout << "debug element-wise iteration over colArray2d:\n  ";
        printDebug(colArray2d);


        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = rowArray2d.begin(); it != rowArray2d.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over colArray2d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = colArray2d.begin(); it != colArray2d.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        // This is because the end iterator, pointing to the indices (2, 0) is
        // (fairly enough) converted into the index 2 by the `storageIndex` function,
        // instead of an index beyond the last element.
        // std::cout << "\ncolumn-major storage index at (2, 0):\n  "
        //           << storageIndex({colArray2d.shape()[0]}, colArray2d.shape(), ColumnMajorStorageOrderTag())
        //           << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\nTest case 3\n"
                  << "-----------\n"
                  << "Both arrays represent the same 4x2x3 matrix:\n"
                  << " 0  1  2    6  7  8    12 13 14    18 19 20\n"
                  << " 3  4  5    9 10 11    15 16 17    21 22 23\n"
                  << std::endl;

        rowArray3d[ 0] =  0; rowArray3d[ 1] =  1; rowArray3d[ 2] =  2;
        rowArray3d[ 3] =  3; rowArray3d[ 4] =  4; rowArray3d[ 5] =  5;

        rowArray3d[ 6] =  6; rowArray3d[ 7] =  7; rowArray3d[ 8] =  8;
        rowArray3d[ 9] =  9; rowArray3d[10] = 10; rowArray3d[11] = 11;

        rowArray3d[12] = 12; rowArray3d[13] = 13; rowArray3d[14] = 14;
        rowArray3d[15] = 15; rowArray3d[16] = 16; rowArray3d[17] = 17;

        rowArray3d[18] = 18; rowArray3d[19] = 19; rowArray3d[20] = 20;
        rowArray3d[21] = 21; rowArray3d[22] = 22; rowArray3d[23] = 23;

        colArray3d[ 0] =  0; colArray3d[ 8] =  1; colArray3d[16] =  2;
        colArray3d[ 4] =  3; colArray3d[12] =  4; colArray3d[20] =  5;

        colArray3d[ 1] =  6; colArray3d[ 9] =  7; colArray3d[17] =  8;
        colArray3d[ 5] =  9; colArray3d[13] = 10; colArray3d[21] = 11;

        colArray3d[ 2] = 12; colArray3d[10] = 13; colArray3d[18] = 14;
        colArray3d[ 6] = 15; colArray3d[14] = 16; colArray3d[22] = 17;

        colArray3d[ 3] = 18; colArray3d[11] = 19; colArray3d[19] = 20;
        colArray3d[ 7] = 21; colArray3d[15] = 22; colArray3d[23] = 23;

        // Below returns 0 1 2 3 4 5 as expected.
        std::cout << "element-wise iteration over rowArray3d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = rowArray3d.elementWiseBegin(); it != rowArray3d.elementWiseEnd(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (expected)" << std::endl;

        // Below returns only 0 instead of 0 1 2 3 4 5.
        std::cout << "element-wise iteration over colArray3d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = colArray3d.elementWiseBegin(); it != colArray3d.elementWiseEnd(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (expected)" << std::endl;

        // But if we increment using the `elementWiseBegin` iterator and use the
        // index number as a stop condition, then it works well.
        std::cout << "debug element-wise iteration over colArray3d:\n  ";
        printDebug(colArray3d);


        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray3d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = rowArray3d.begin(); it != rowArray3d.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over colArray3d:\n  ";
        for (auto it = colArray3d.begin(); it != colArray3d.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 6 12 18 3 9 15 21 1 7 13 19 4 10 16 22 2 8 14 20 5 11 17 23 (expected)" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code output:

```
Test case 1
-----------
Both arrays represent the same 2x3 matrix:
  0 1 2
  3 4 5
element-wise iteration over rowArray2d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
element-wise iteration over colArray2d:
  0 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
debug element-wise iteration over colArray2d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray2d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over colArray2d:
  0 3 1 4 2 5 
  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)

Test case 2
-----------
Both arrays share the same internal 1-D representation:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
element-wise iteration over rowArray2d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
element-wise iteration over colArray2d:
  0 
  0 2 4 1 3 5 (expected)
debug element-wise iteration over colArray2d:
  0 2 4 1 3 5 
internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray2d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over colArray2d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)

Test case 3
-----------
Both arrays represent the same 4x2x3 matrix:
 0  1  2    6  7  8    12 13 14    18 19 20
 3  4  5    9 10 11    15 16 17    21 22 23

element-wise iteration over rowArray3d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (expected)
element-wise iteration over colArray3d:
  0 1 2 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (expected)
debug element-wise iteration over colArray3d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray3d:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over colArray3d:
  0 6 12 18 3 9 15 21 1 7 13 19 4 10 16 22 2 8 14 20 5 11 17 23 
  0 6 12 18 3 9 15 21 1 7 13 19 4 10 16 22 2 8 14 20 5 11 17 23 (expected)
```

**Edit**

The purpose of this iterator is to do element-wise operations between arrays having different storage orders, such as comparing the elements for equality.

As such, the iterator should traverse the array elements in a predefined order (row-major here). That is, when initializing the iterator for a `2 x 3` array with the `elementWiseBegin()` method, it should point to the element at the index `(0, 0)`. When incrementing it, it should point to `(0, 1)`, then `(0, 2)`, then `(1, 0)`, and so on.

This ensures that, during an iteration process, an element from a first array located at the index `(0, 2)` can be compared to the element of a second array located at the same index `(0, 2)`, and thus regardless of their storage order.

**Edit 2**

It seems that there is some confusion around the definition of row/column major storage orders. When I'm talking of storage order, I'm referring to the layout in memory as per [the definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), not to the [vector orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_vector).

A different storage order shouldn't change the way the array is presented to the user. Indeed, a `2 x 3` array will always be noted as below, with the elements representing their indices.

```
+----+----+----+
| 00 | 01 | 02 |
+----+----+----+
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
+----+----+----+
```

What a different storage order does though, is aligning differently the elements within the internal representation in memory, ie:

```
// Row-major storage order.
00 01 02 10 11 12

// Column-major storage order.
00 10 01 11 02 12
```

When setting directly the internal data with `0 1 2 3 4 5` as done within my snippet, and according to what was said just before, this is how I expect the arrays to look like:

```
// Row-major storage order.
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+

// Column-major storage order.
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 2 | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
```

The goal of the element-wise iterator is to always return the elements in the order `00 01 02 10 11 12`, regardless of the storage order. That's why when setting directly the internal data with `0 1 2 3 4 5`, I'm expecting this element-wise iterator to return the elements in the order `0 1 2 3 4 5` when using the row-major storage order, and `0 2 4 1 3 5` in the case of a column-major storage order.

Comment: why do you want to be independant of the storage order? It does make sense to iterate in storage order because of caches 'n' stuff.

Comment: The storage-dependant order for the caches 'n' stuff is handled by the iterator returned from the `begin/end` methods. This one is for when an indices correspondance matters for element-wise operations, as explained in my edit. Otherwise how could I compare the elements for equality between two arrays having different storage order?

Comment: Why is storage order even important as the underlying data is encapsulated anyway? I mean, it is an implementation detail.

Comment: Then let me know how you iterate in the same order (indices-wise) through two arrays having different storage orders.

Comment: A few questions, #1, you seem to have implemented this to be multidimensional, yet all of your code and examples only seem to be concerned about 2d matrices, is n-dimensional a use case, and if so, how does one normally express the storage order of an n-dimensional matrix?  You're using an enum class instead of a more general solution.  (Hint, what's a method of numbering the permutations of a set of unique elements?) #2, why are you using a bidirectional iterator instead of a random access one?  Code complexity?  #3 what are you seeking from an answer?  There isn't a single ? in your question

Comment: #1 Disclaimer: I'm totally novice with the n-dimensional concept. I do want the array to be n-dimensional (admittedly mainly for learning purposes), and I find that the row/column major notations fall apart with more than 2 dimensions so for now I'm respectively expressing them in the final code as first/last major instead, with the last major meaning that the last dimension is contiguous in memory. I left the row/column major notation here to avoid confusion. I'm also open to better implementation ideas, as soon as it's simple to use/understand.
1/2

Comment: And since the current problem already breaks with 2 dimensions, I thought that it would be easier to stick with 2 dimensions for this question.
#2 I thought about implementing a random access iterator but a bidirectional one would be a good start already. If I get this to work, then I'll definitely try to promote it.
#3 I'm simply looking for a way to get my code to work. I believe that it actually all works when the iterator is within the bound of the array but I fail at expressing an end iterator, or iterators beyond the end element.
2/2

Comment: I replaced the reference to your github library with a condensed version of the only function you were using out of that library.  Now your example code is actually self-contained, which helps with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Storing values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,` into a 1-D array which represents a row major 2-D array (2 rows, 3 columns) when memory access is row major:

Storage order:

```
[
    0, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5
]

i.e., [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Storing values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,` into a 1-D array which represents a column major 2-D array (2 rows, 3 columns) when memory access is row major:

Storage order:

```
[
    0, 2, 4,
    1, 3, 5
]

i.e., [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
```

You state:

> The purpose of this iterator is to do element-wise operations between arrays having different storage orders, such as comparing the elements for equality.

I take this to mean the row major array should store its data differently than the column major array **and a special iterator should be available such that each array can be iterated in the same *logical order* (e.g., to compare if they are equivalent)**. Assuming I understand your question then the row/column major arrays will be in memory as shown above. However, using a **special iterator** enforcing a row major ordering causes each array to visit its values in the same *logical order* (i.e., `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

### Code output (I added the comments):

```
// This shows the storage order is as describe above
storage order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
storage order: { 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 }

// This shows that both can be iterated in the same 'logical order'
r major order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
r major order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

/*********************************
 * Works for arbitrary N-D array *
 *********************************/

// 3-D
storage order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
storage order: { 0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7 }
r major order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
r major order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }

// 4-D
storage order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
storage order: { 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 }
r major order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
r major order: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }

Test case 1
-----------
Both arrays represent the same 2x3 matrix:
  0 1 2
  3 4 5
row major iteration over rowArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
row major iteration over colArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over colArray:
  0 3 1 4 2 5
  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)
col major iteration over rowArray:
  0 3 1 4 2 5
  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)
col major iteration over colArray:
  0 3 1 4 2 5
  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)

Test case 2
-----------
Both arrays share the same internal 1-D representation:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
row major iteration over rowArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
row major iteration over colArray:
  0 2 4 1 3 5
  0 2 4 1 3 5 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
internal 1-D data iteration over colArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
col major iteration over rowArray:
  0 3 1 4 2 5
  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)
col major iteration over colArray:
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)
```

### The code:

Supports row major or column major iteration for arbitrary dimensionality.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class StorageOrder
{
    rowMajor,
    columnMajor
};

template<typename T>
constexpr T product(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 * t2;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr T product(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    return t * product(ts...);
}

template<StorageOrder T_iterOrder, std::size_t... T_dimensions>
class ArrayIndexer
{
public:
    using Indices = const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;

    static std::size_t computeIndex(const Indices& indices)
    {
        const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)> indexSizes = { T_dimensions... };

        std::size_t index = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof... (T_dimensions); ++i)
        {
            std::size_t result = 1;
            for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < sizeof... (T_dimensions); ++j)
            {
                result *= indexSizes[j];
            }

            result *= indices[i];
            index += result;
        }

        return index;
    }
};

template<std::size_t... T_dimensions>
class ArrayIndexer<StorageOrder::columnMajor, T_dimensions...>
{
public:
    using Indices = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;

    static std::size_t computeIndex(const Indices& indices)
    {
        const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)> indexSizes = { T_dimensions... };

        std::size_t index = indices[0];
        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < sizeof... (T_dimensions); ++i)
        {
            std::size_t result = 1;
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            {
                result *= indexSizes[j];
            }

            result *= indices[i];
            index += result;
        }

        return index;
    }
};

template<typename T, StorageOrder T_storageOrder, StorageOrder T_iterOrder, std::size_t... T_dimensions>
class ArrayIterator
{
public:
    using Storage = std::array<T, product(T_dimensions...)>;
    using IndexSizes = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;
    using Indices = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;

    ArrayIterator(Storage& array, const Indices& indices) :
        mArray(array)
    {
        IndexSizes indexSizes = { T_dimensions... };
        if (indices == indexSizes)
        {
            mIndex = mArray.size();
        }
        else
        {
            mIndex = ArrayIndexer<T_iterOrder, T_dimensions...>::computeIndex(indices);
        }
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const ArrayIterator& other) const
    {
        return &mArray == &other.mArray && mIndex == other.mIndex;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const ArrayIterator& other) const
    {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return mArray[mIndex];
    }

    ArrayIterator& operator++()
    {
        ++mIndex;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::size_t mIndex;
    Storage &mArray;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t... T_dimensions>
class ArrayIterator<T, StorageOrder::rowMajor, StorageOrder::columnMajor, T_dimensions...>
{
public:
    using Storage = std::array<T, product(T_dimensions...)>;
    using IndexSizes = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;
    using Indices = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;

    ArrayIterator(Storage& array, const Indices& indices) :
        mIndexSizes({ T_dimensions... }),
        mIndices(indices),
        mArray(array)
    {
        if (mIndices == mIndexSizes)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mIndices.size() - 1; ++i)
            {
                mIndices[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const ArrayIterator& other) const
    {
        return &mArray == &other.mArray && mIndices == other.mIndices;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const ArrayIterator& other) const
    {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return mArray[ArrayIndexer<StorageOrder::rowMajor, T_dimensions...>::computeIndex(mIndices)];
    }

    ArrayIterator& operator++()
    {
        advance(0);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void advance(std::size_t incrementIndex)
    {
        if (++mIndices[incrementIndex] == mIndexSizes[incrementIndex])
        {
            if (incrementIndex < sizeof... (T_dimensions) - 1)
            {
                mIndices[incrementIndex] = 0;
                advance(incrementIndex + 1);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    IndexSizes mIndexSizes;
    Indices mIndices;
    Storage &mArray;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t... T_dimensions>
class ArrayIterator<T, StorageOrder::columnMajor, StorageOrder::rowMajor, T_dimensions...>
{
public:
    using Storage = std::array<T, product(T_dimensions...)>;
    using IndexSizes = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;
    using Indices = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof... (T_dimensions)>;

    ArrayIterator(Storage& array, const Indices& indices) :
        mIndexSizes({ T_dimensions... }),
        mIndices(indices),
        mArray(array)
    {
        if (mIndices == mIndexSizes)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 1; i < mIndices.size(); ++i)
            {
                mIndices[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const ArrayIterator& other) const
    {
        return &mArray == &other.mArray && mIndices == other.mIndices;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const ArrayIterator& other) const
    {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return mArray[ArrayIndexer<StorageOrder::columnMajor, T_dimensions...>::computeIndex(mIndices)];
    }

    ArrayIterator& operator++()
    {
        advance(sizeof... (T_dimensions) - 1);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void advance(std::size_t incrementIndex)
    {
        if (++mIndices[incrementIndex] == mIndexSizes[incrementIndex])
        {
            if (incrementIndex > 0)
            {
                mIndices[incrementIndex] = 0;
                advance(incrementIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    IndexSizes mIndexSizes;
    Indices mIndices;
    Storage &mArray;
};

template<typename T, StorageOrder T_storageOrder, std::size_t... T_dimensions>
class Array
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t StorageSize = product(T_dimensions...);
    using Storage = std::array<T, StorageSize>;

    using iterator = typename Storage::iterator;
    using iterator_row = ArrayIterator<T, T_storageOrder, StorageOrder::rowMajor, T_dimensions...>;
    using iterator_col = ArrayIterator<T, T_storageOrder, StorageOrder::columnMajor, T_dimensions...>;

    constexpr bool empty() const
    {
        return mArray.empty();
    }

    constexpr std::size_t size() const
    {
        return mArray.size();
    }

    iterator begin()
    {
        return mArray.begin();
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return mArray.end();
    }

    iterator_row beginRowMajor()
    {
        return iterator_row(mArray, { 0, 0 });
    }

    iterator_row endRowMajor()
    {
        return iterator_row(mArray, { T_dimensions... });
    }

    iterator_col beginColMajor()
    {
        return iterator_col(mArray, { 0, 0 });
    }

    iterator_col endColMajor()
    {
        return iterator_col(mArray, { T_dimensions... });
    }

    T& operator[](std::size_t index)
    {
        return mArray[index];
    }

    const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const
    {
        return mArray[index];
    }

private:
    Storage mArray;
};

template<typename T, StorageOrder S, std::size_t... D>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Array<T, S, D...>& array)
{
    stream << "{";
    if (!array.empty())
    {
        std::size_t index = 0;
        stream << " " << array[index];
        while (++index < array.size())
        {
            stream << ", " << array[index];
        }
    }
    stream << " }";

    return stream;
}

template<typename T, StorageOrder S, std::size_t... D>
void printRowMajor(Array<T, S, D...>& array)
{
    std::cout << "{";
    auto itr = array.beginRowMajor();
    if (itr != array.endRowMajor())
    {
        std::cout << " " << *itr;
        while (++itr != array.endRowMajor())
        {
            std::cout << ", " << *itr;
        }
    }
    std::cout << " }";
}

int main()
{
    {
        Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 2, 3> rowMajorArray;
        int i = -1;
        // Store the data directly to the array
        for (auto& v : rowMajorArray)
        {
            v = ++i;
        }

        Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 2, 3> colMajorArray;
        i = -1;
        // Store the data directly to the array
        for (auto& v : colMajorArray)
        {
            v = ++i;
        }

        std::cout << "storage order: " << rowMajorArray << "\n";
        std::cout << "storage order: " << colMajorArray << "\n";
        std::cout << "r major order: "; printRowMajor(rowMajorArray); std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "r major order: "; printRowMajor(colMajorArray); std::cout << "\n";
    }

    {
        Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 2, 2, 2> rowMajorArray;
        int i = -1;
        // Store the data directly to the array
        for (auto& v : rowMajorArray)
        {
            v = ++i;
        }

        Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 2, 2, 2> colMajorArray;
        i = -1;
        // Store the data directly to the array
        for (auto& v : colMajorArray)
        {
            v = ++i;
        }

        std::cout << "storage order: " << rowMajorArray << "\n";
        std::cout << "storage order: " << colMajorArray << "\n";
        std::cout << "r major order: "; printRowMajor(rowMajorArray); std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "r major order: "; printRowMajor(colMajorArray); std::cout << "\n";
    }

    {
        Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 2, 2, 2, 2> rowMajorArray;
        int i = -1;
        // Store the data directly to the array
        for (auto& v : rowMajorArray)
        {
            v = ++i;
        }

        Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 2, 2, 2, 2> colMajorArray;
        i = -1;
        // Store the data directly to the array
        for (auto& v : colMajorArray)
        {
            v = ++i;
        }

        std::cout << "storage order: " << rowMajorArray << "\n";
        std::cout << "storage order: " << colMajorArray << "\n";
        std::cout << "r major order: "; printRowMajor(rowMajorArray); std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "r major order: "; printRowMajor(colMajorArray); std::cout << "\n";
    }

    {
        Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 2, 3> rowArray;
        Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 2, 3> colArray;

        rowArray[0] = 0; rowArray[1] = 1; rowArray[2] = 2;
        rowArray[3] = 3; rowArray[4] = 4; rowArray[5] = 5;

        colArray[0] = 0; colArray[2] = 1; colArray[4] = 2;
        colArray[1] = 3; colArray[3] = 4; colArray[5] = 5;

        std::cout
            << "\nTest case 1\n"
            << "-----------\n"
            << "Both arrays represent the same 2x3 matrix:\n"
            << "  0 1 2\n"
            << "  3 4 5\n";

        std::cout << "row major iteration over rowArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = rowArray.beginRowMajor(); itr != rowArray.endRowMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)\n";

        std::cout << "row major iteration over colArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = colArray.beginRowMajor(); itr != colArray.endRowMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)\n";

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = rowArray.begin(); itr != rowArray.end(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over colArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = colArray.begin(); itr != colArray.end(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "col major iteration over rowArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = rowArray.beginColMajor(); itr != rowArray.endColMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)\n";

        std::cout << "col major iteration over colArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = colArray.beginColMajor(); itr != colArray.endColMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)\n";
    }

    {
        Array<int, StorageOrder::rowMajor, 2, 3> rowArray;
        Array<int, StorageOrder::columnMajor, 2, 3> colArray;

        rowArray[0] = 0; rowArray[1] = 1; rowArray[2] = 2;
        rowArray[3] = 3; rowArray[4] = 4; rowArray[5] = 5;

        colArray[0] = 0; colArray[2] = 2; colArray[4] = 4;
        colArray[1] = 1; colArray[3] = 3; colArray[5] = 5;

        std::cout
            << "\nTest case 2\n"
            << "-----------\n"
            << "Both arrays share the same internal 1-D representation:\n"
            << "  0 1 2 3 4 5\n";

        std::cout << "row major iteration over rowArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = rowArray.beginRowMajor(); itr != rowArray.endRowMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)\n";

        std::cout << "row major iteration over colArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = colArray.beginRowMajor(); itr != colArray.endRowMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 2 4 1 3 5 (expected)\n";

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over rowArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = rowArray.begin(); itr != rowArray.end(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "internal 1-D data iteration over colArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = colArray.begin(); itr != colArray.end(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "col major iteration over rowArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = rowArray.beginColMajor(); itr != rowArray.endColMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 3 1 4 2 5 (expected)\n";

        std::cout << "col major iteration over colArray:\n  ";
        for (auto itr = colArray.beginColMajor(); itr != colArray.endColMajor(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n  0 1 2 3 4 5 (expected)\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question to explain why I'm not expecting `0 3 1 4 2 5` in the case of a column-major storage order, but the second part of your code works well. Your incrementing code seems similar to eigen's comma-initializer, and is indeed straightforward for 2 dimensions. The fun begins with n-dimensions :)

Comment: I have updated my solution. I believe it behaves the way you want and it should also support arbitrary dimensionality.

Comment: Sorry James but you've changed the behaviour of the `begin()` and `end()` members when they were simply referring to the internal `std::array` as expected. This causes your second code output to be errorneous: it should be equal to what you're setting up within the range-based loop, that is `{0 1 2 3 4 5}`.
I have updated the code in my question to hopefully provide better and more comprehensible test cases.

Comment: The test cases helped a lot. I'll update my solution again (hopefully for the last time).

Comment: @ChristopherC Take a look at my latest answer and let me know if you see any problems.

Comment: I have updated the test cases because you once again modified the `begin()` and `end()` iterators when you really shouldn't. These work as expected in the question's code and modifying them can only result in changing their behaviour in a buggy way. Now, I actually found a solution to this problem but I'm not such a big fan of it, see my answer.
Also, it is being said in the guidelines to not post such comments, but really thank you for your efforts James, you are incredibly persistent and determined, which I believe is highly valuable.

Comment: @ChristopherC I'm sorry for my comment. I'm still rather new to SO so thanks for bringing the comment to my attention, I won't comment that way again. Is your point just that the `begin` and `end` iterators are not the typical `std::array` iterators? If so, only a minor change to the types for those functions is needed. I updated my answer again. Unless I hear back from you I won't bother you about this question anymore.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding! What I meant is that the guidelines ask to avoid posting comments such as “thank you” but I couldn't resist thanking you anyways! :) Nothing wrong with your comments!
This last edit of yours seems to work perfectly, including in n-dimensions from a test that I've just made (and if my understanding is correct).
At the end of the day I'm not sure what would be the advantage of your code over the one provided in my question + answer? Maybe I'm missing something, I definitely need to dig more into your logic but I've been having some difficulties to understand it all.

Comment: @ChristopherC I see, thanks for clearing up the misunderstanding. As for your solution versus mine I can't say which is _better_, if yours also works for n-dimensions. My solution allows you to choose between row or column major iteration which could be useful to compare against other array types without having to temporarily copy them into this `Array` class. The part of my solution that could probably use improvement is if the recursive `advance` function was converted to an iterative solution.

Comment: @ChristopherC I could probably add some comments/documentation to my code if you let me know which parts/functions would be most beneficial to you.

Comment: You are too good with me James! :) Don't worry about it, I will figure it out when I'll have some time to analyze your methods individually. Also I have edited my question to add a test case for 3-D arrays, just for the fun of it. Thanks again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that in the `operator++` of `ElementWiseIterator` you are increasing the `_currentIndices` variable always in a row major way, which prevents you from doing what you want. In fact, it is not even needed to have two different `storageIndex` functions, given that their only purpose should be to convert from an N-dimensional index to a 1-dimensional one.

Given this, I've implemented a small corrective fix; it's not incredibly pretty but it works, and you can prettify it later however you feel like.

```
ElementWiseIterator & operator++()
{
    std::size_t i = _shape.size();
    // The idea here is that we keep exactly the same code to increase the index,
    // since that's working fine.
    // However, in column Major order the difference is that we treat the
    // column index as the first index we want to try to increment. Thus,
    // we simply swap it with the row index here, and at the end of the procedure.
    if ( T_storageOrder == StorageOrder::columnMajor ) {
        std::swap(_shape[T_dimensionality-1], _shape[T_dimensionality-2]);
        std::swap(_currentIndices[T_dimensionality-1], _currentIndices[T_dimensionality-2]);
    }
    // For each dimension
    while (i-- > 0) {
        // Find the lowest index one can increase
        // Indeces are stored from top to bottom
        if (_currentIndices[i] < _shape[i] - 1) {
            ++_currentIndices[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    // We want to know if we reached the end of the container.
    // I don't think there's an easy way to directly set the final
    // index from here, given that another swap still needs to happen.
    // So we save this information and use it later.
    bool endOfContainer = ( i == -1 );

    // Then we reset all the others, since they could not be increased.
    for (++i; i < _currentIndices.size(); ++i) {
        _currentIndices[i] = 0;
    }

    if ( T_storageOrder == StorageOrder::columnMajor ) {
        std::swap(_shape[T_dimensionality-1], _shape[T_dimensionality-2]);
        std::swap(_currentIndices[T_dimensionality-1], _currentIndices[T_dimensionality-2]);
    }
    // We manually set the last element
    if ( endOfContainer )
        _currentIndices[0] = _shape[0];

    setCurrentElement();
    return *this;
}

// .....

void setCurrentElement()
{
    // This storageIndex is the row major one; the other you can delete!
    std::size_t index = storageIndex(
        _currentIndices,
        _shape
    );
    _currentElement = &(*_data)[index];
}
```

You can try this code out here: http://ideone.com/7Y7LOa

EDIT: Regarding comparisons of elements independently of storage order, as I said you can use the iterators to write in the matrices too. This code shows how to write and compare elements from two matrices, one using row major order and the other column major. You can see that in the end the internal storage differs, but the iterators still allow you to compare elements directly.

http://ideone.com/fzu7uE

Comment: It should return `0 2 4 1 3 5` instead of `0 3 1 4 2 5` in the column-major order case.
Also, I do want to enforce the row-major iteration with both storage orders. The idea is for example to do an element-wise comparison of two arrays having different storage orders. In such a case, I've got to pick one direction of iteration and stick with it for both arrays.

Comment: @ChristopherC A 2x3 matrix means two rows of three colums each, thus the result returned is correct. In addition, neither your code or mine modifies storage order, so your request makes little sense. You only do the reading in a specific order, since that code is in the iterator advance function. You always write using the underlying std::array begin/end functions, so that would be row-major I guess.

Comment: @ChristopherC If you instead want to write using a specific order, you can use one iterator order to write, and the other to read. I don't really see where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, a 2x3 array always represents 2 arrays of 3 elements each, regardless of the storage order, and the data in my code is indeed set using the underlying std::array begin/end functions, thus setting directly the internal 1-D storage. Hence, in the case of a column-major storage order, I expect the first row to be `0 2 4` and the second one to be `1 3 5`, resulting in the element-wise (row-major) iterator to return `0 2 4 1 3 5`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristopherC I think we're visualizing the data differently, but I mean you can modify the algorithm how you wish your matrix to work. Personally, I see the code filling the  underlying array with `0 1 2 3 4 5` as having a first row with `0 1 2` and a second row with `3 4 5`.

Comment: @ChristopherC Thus when visualizing it column-wise, you get `0 3`, `1 4` and `2 5`. If you want your result, try a 3x2 matrix.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I understand, you're trying to reverse the order in which the `operator++` is incrementing the `_currentIndices` member. If it's correct, I believe that we're still not on the same page. I do want the `_currentIndices` member to be incremented the same way (in a row-major fashion) regardless of the storage order.

Comment: I see the storage order as being only an implementation detail defining how the data is layed out within the internal 1-D storage. This shouldn't influence how the element-wise iterator behaves—in the case of a 2x3 array, the element-wise iterator `begin` should return the element at the index (0, 0). Incrementing from there will return (0, 1), then (0, 2), then (1, 0), and so on, thus regardless of the storage order. I believe that my approach is correct, I'm just having issues at defining iterations past the range of the array, such as with the `end` iterator and beyond.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to increment `_currentIndices` in the same way. I think you should clarify your question if you have particular requirements. As I understood it, you want to implement an iterator which iterates differently based on a row/column order. If what you want is different, you should clarify your question.

Comment: If I don't increment `_currentIndices` the same way, then how can I compare all the elements from two arrays having different storage orders, in such a way that the element (0, 2) of the first array compares with the element (0, 2) of the second array, and so on.
I'm definitely not good at describing my problems though, so I've edited my question to try to improve it as you've suggested.

Comment: I'm sorry but the logic behind your code cannot do what I want. And flipping a 2x3 array into a 3x2 array only to get this specific result correct is nothing less than a hack. I guess I'm just too bad at making you understand what I really need, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple answer to my question but I have a gut feeling that it isn't that clean, and that it adds yet some more overhead even though I haven't profiled it.

It consists in updating the `ElementWiseIterator::operator==()` method from the question from

```
friend bool operator==(const ElementWiseIterator &iterator1, const ElementWiseIterator &iterator2)
{ return iterator1._currentElement == iterator2._currentElement; }
```

to

```
friend bool operator==(const ElementWiseIterator &iterator1, const ElementWiseIterator &iterator2)
{ return iterator1._currentIndices == iterator2._currentIndices; }
```

and thus basically comparing the current indices of the iterators rather than the address of the current elements.

Answer (score -1):

you can implement the iterators depending on the Storage order entirely different.

```
struct ElementWiseIterator<StorageOrder so>;

template<>
struct ElementWiseIterator<StorageOrder::rowMajor> {
    [...]
};

template<>
struct ElementWiseIterator<StorageOrder::columnMajor> {
    [...]
};

template <StorageOrder so> 
class Array {
    ElementWiseIterator<so> elementWiseBegin() { 
        return ElementWiseIterator<so>(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: I already know how to do template specialization, thank you, but this has nothing to do with the question.