# Iterator 2D vector by column

Tags: c++

What changes I need to do if I want to go through a vector like this, column by column instead line by line?

```
vector<vector<bool>> vvi(nLin, vector<bool>(nCol, false));

vector< vector<bool> >::iterator row;
vector<bool>::iterator col;

    for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); row++) {
        for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
            // do stuff ...
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably can't use iterators for that (unless you write your own), but indexing via subscript should work (`vvi[row][col]`)

Comment: Wait `int` or `bool`?

Comment: Rotate the matrix?

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312565/element-wise-multidimensional-array-iteration-regardless-of-storage-order/28519117#28519117) of how you could write some generic code which allows the data to be stored in either row or column major and can be iterated in row or column major regardless of the storage order. Note: It should work for arbitrary dimensions (e.g., 2D, 3D, 4D, etc).

Comment: The biggest problem with a matrix is there is no bloody spoon.

Comment: Oh man...I was asked this same question at an interview, using a 2d iterator

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `vector<vector<T>>` for this, then you can only iterate in one order. Note that this is neither row-by-row nor column-by-column, but in reality vector-by-vector. Each sub-vector has storage allocated completely independently from the other vector and could even be of different length, so it's hard to call it a "row".

If you want a matrix-like (tensor-like in general) storage, you should consider using some library that provides that (STL does not), for example OpenCV, or wrap a single contiguous `vector` into your own class that does the indexing.

```
struct Matrix {
   std::vector<bool> storage;
   int ncols;
   Matrix(int nrows, int ncols) : storage(nrows * ncols), ncols(ncols) {}
   bool& operator[](int row, int col) {
      return storage[row * ncols + col];
   }
};
```

Then you can iterate using plain `for` loops or write your own iterators.

If that's too much work, you can stick with `vector<vector<bool>>` but use `operator[]` instead of iterators:

```
for (int col = 0; col < nCols; ++col) {
   for (int row = 0; row < nRows; ++row) {
      bool& el = vvi[row][col];
      // do stuff on el
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `ncols`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the number of columns, nCol, you can produce iterators this way:

```
for (size_t colNo = 0; colNo < nCol; ++colNo) {
    for (const auto& row: vvi) {
        auto it = row.begin() + colNo;
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If you don't actually need iterators:

```
for (size_t colNo = 0; colNo < nCol; ++colNo) {
    for (const auto& row: vvi) {
        bool colVal = row.at(colNo);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use iterators:

```
int row = 0;            // V You could also use ncol below, if you know it wont change. 
for (int col = 0; col < vvi.at(row).size(); col++) {
    for (row = 0; row < vvi.size(); row++) {
        // get current value by vvi.at(row).at(col)
    }
}
```

This is unsafe though, if you do not know that each of your rows are the same size. Thats why we use `.at(` or you can do your own bounds checking.